# how to pass pagination params as post in yii2?

Tags: php, post, get, yii2

I need to pass pagination params as post if it is possible in yii2.

```
             I used pagination=>[ params => array() ];
```

But while pagination that values are going as `get`. Like index.php&array=value.
I need that values as `post`.
Thanks for advance..

Comment: You could do it with JS. However, why do you want to use POST? I think you have a conceptual mistake if you need this.

Comment: @robsh I used my own form so while pagination that values doesn't go. I want to pass that so I choose params in pagination. If any other way is there to send values while pagination as post?